# How to use jQuery to add css style only to certain elements

Tags: jquery, html

Can someone please tell me how can I add a css style to elements that have `height > 22px`?

I've made something but the css style is added to all elements...

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hbz0d1db/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
  <div class="row">
    word word word word word word word word word word word word
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    word word word word
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word     word word word word
  </div>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="row">
    word word word word word word word word word word word word
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    word word word word
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word     word word word word
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
if ($('.row').height() > 22) {
    $('.row').css({'background-color':'blue'})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use .each() method to specify to run for each matched element.

```
$(".row").each(function() {
  if ($(this).height() > 22) {
    $(this).css({
      'background-color': 'blue'
    })
  }
});
```

**[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/hbz0d1db/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** function here:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```js
$(function(){
 $('.row').filter(function(){
   return $(this).height() > 22;
 }).css({'background-color':'blue'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
  <div class="row">
    word word word word word word word word word word word word
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    word word word word
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word     word word word word
  </div>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <div class="row">
    word word word word word word word word word word word word
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    word word word word
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word     word word word word
  </div>
</div>
```